# Python the same name for the global and the parameter variable

Tags: python, global-variables

Имею вот такой код

```
executor = None
active_obj = None

def set_context(**context):
    global executor, active_obj
    executor    = context.get('executor')
    active_obj  = context.get('active_obj')

    assert executor, 'You must provide a context with an executor!'
```

Примеры вызовов функции

```
set_context(executor=my_executor)
set_context(**{'executor':my_executor})
```

Должны работать оба вызова с параметром executor. (В данной модели и работают)

Хочу сделать параметр executor обязательным параметром в объявлении функции.
(Переход на ООП не предлагать, executor должен быть глобальным)

```
def set_context(executor, **context):
    global executor, active_obj
    executor    = executor
    active_obj  = context.get('active_obj')
```

Логично, что такой код работать не может, альтернативный вариант

```
def set_context(executor, **context):
    l1 = executor
    global executor, active_obj
    executor    = l1
    active_obj  = context.get('active_obj')
```

К сожалению, в Python такое не работает :(

Был ещё вариант

```
def set_context(executor, **context):
    global active_obj
    from . import executor as g_executor
    g_executor  = executor
    active_obj  = context.get('active_obj')
```

Но при присваивании в g_executor, он теряет связь с глобальной переменной и такой подход годится только на чтение

Возможно ли сделать что-то в духе

```
def set_context(executor, **context):
    global executor as g_executor, active_obj
    g_executor  = executor
    active_obj  = context.get('active_obj')
```

Единственный альтернативный рабочий код, который мне совсем не нравится (лучше оставить оригинальный вариант)

```
def set_context(executor, **context):
    __set_context(executor, context)

def __set_context(_executor, context):
    global executor, active_obj
    executor    = _executor
    active_obj  = context.get('active_obj')
```

Comment: Какие-то дикие костыли. Оставьте первый вариант и не мучайтесь.

Comment: Кстати, чем мотивировано то чтобы executor обязательно был глобальным?

Comment: @insolor Для простоты разработки огромного множества скриптов, которые полностью вертятся вокруг 20+ функций из этого модуля. Если все эти функции обернуть в класс вместе с executor и active_obj, то их вызов будет происходить через wrapper_obj.executor, например. Когда твой каждый скрипт под 1к строк и из них более 50%, это слово wrapper_obj, то тут начинаешь понимать, что что-то идёт не так. Поэтому принял решение, что все функции в модуле должны быть глобальными. В моём случае сильно упрощает разработку :) А так да, такой вариант не должен использоваться в обычной ситуации.

Comment: Ну так используйте сокращенное имя, типа `wo = WrapperObject()`, потом `wo.executor`.

Comment: @insolor
Думал вообще сокращать до одной буквы по началу. Но вариант вообще без него мне нравится больше :)
Пример: [ссылка](https://ibb.co/5jcDFkS)

Comment: А `wo.get('id')` вместо возможного `wo.id` вас не смущает?

Comment: @insolor ни чуть. Я могу переопределить через поведение wo через __getattr__. Но, изменим мы например wo.get('id') на wo.id. Но id - это атрибут объекта item. А атрbбут может иметь имена и через дефис, через пробел, имя атрибута может совпасть с именем метода wo. В это случае нужно делать 2 метода, как сейчас через get и ваш вариант. При этом постоянно помнить, какой атрибут можно через точку, какой нельзя? Да и понятность кода сильно упадёт. В одном месте через get, в другом напрямую через точку. Уж лучше единый интерфейс, всё через get.

Comment: @insolor А так, можно, например, переопределить __getitem__, чтоб обращаться wo['id'], wo['attr with spaces']. Но тут тоже есть проблема, на практике get принимает 8 аргументов, 7 из опционально. Как же быть с ними?

Comment: Ну так сделайте `item` отдельным объектом, вместо одного "god object". `source`, я так понимаю - то же самый `item`, только вложенный, получится `item.source.id`).

Comment: `Да и понятность кода сильно упадёт. В одном месте через get, в другом напрямую через точку.` - вообще везде убрать `get`, тогда не упадет. По поводу количества параметров - смотря что там у вас за параметры, тоже можно что-то придумать.

Comment: @insolor тут нет "god object", тут есть понятие активный объект в данный момент времени. item может быть, например, словарём, а может быть XML записью (есть и другие виды). Это значит, что все item должны быть также упакованы в специальный класс, который позволит обращаться к ним через точку и вызывать внутри item этот же метод wo.get. (PS такой класс уже есть ;) Но это накладные расходы, т.к. item'ов может быть несколько  миллионов, а конвертировать по-хорошему лишь в исключительных ситуациях. А также в вашем варианте, например, нельзя задать значение по умолчанию.

Comment: @insolor Вот описание метода
`get(key, position=0, _global=False, on_obj=None, multiple=False, wait_timeout=0, raw=True, required=True)`
Параметры:

`key` - что ищем, например 'id'
`position` - если работаем с иттерируемым объектом, то взятие его по индексу (не обязательно числовой). В случае через точку индекс можно переопределить, чтоб работал как с массивом.
`_global` - игнорировать активный элемент (поиск по всему документу). В случае через точку вынос в отдельную функцию глобальный поиск.

Comment: @insolor 
`on_obj` - игнорировать активный элемент. По сути если item не активный, то get('id' on_obj=item), что в варианте через точку просто item.id и этот параметр становится бесполезным
`multiple` - поиск всех элементов (по умолчанию, первый найденный)
`wait_timeout` - если элемент ещё не доступен для загрузки, то максимальное время ожидания
`raw` - если raw=False, то найденный объект конвертируется в объект с возможностью обращения через точку. В вашем вариант это всегда True
`required` - если объект не будет найден, то генерируется ошибка

Comment: @insolor 
Но не забываем, что многие атрибуты имею пробелы в имени
get('Дата добавления') != item.Дата добавления

Comment: По поводу пробелов - можно реализовать обращение и через точку, и через квадратные скобки, в обоих случаях без get. По поводу параметров get - если они меняются редко, то можно просто менять их как свойства класса. По поводу накладных расходов - нужно мерять. Можно сначала хотя бы получить список элементов, а при обращении к полям уже получать сами значения объектов.

Comment: @insolor 
В целом читабельность кода улучшается, особенно если его будет смотреть человек, впервые работающий с моим модулем.
Но вариант, без wo, где функции глобальные мне всё равно нравится больше :)
А вопрос свой, кстати, я решил (от которого мы давно ушли)

Также get является самой наиболее часто вызываемой функцией, и поэтому делать обёртку над ним путём конвертации всех item в специальный объект не хочу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл, что доступ к словарю глобальных переменных можно получить, через функцию `globals`

В итоге код получился такой, и меня вполне устраивает :)

```
executor = None
active_obj = None

__globals__ = globals()

def set_context(executor, **context):
    global active_obj

    assert executor, 'You must provide an executor!'

    __globals__['executor'] = executor
    active_obj = context.get('active_obj')
```

Задача на использование параметра и глобальной переменной с одним именем внутри функции решена